# SQL query Splitting a column into Multiple rows divide by percentage

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

How to get percentage of a column and then inserting it as rows

```
Col1    item    TotalAmount**
1        ABC    5558767.82
2        ABC    4747605.5
3        ABC    667377.69
4        ABC    3844204
6        CTB    100
7        CTB    500.52
```

I need to create a new column percentage for each item which is I have done  as  :-
*Select  item,  (totalAmount/select sum(totalAmount) from table1) as Percentage
From table1 
Group by item*

```
Col1    item    TotalAmount      percentage
1       ABC     5558767.82       38
2       ABC     4747605.5        32
3       ABC     667377.69        5
4       ABC     3844204          26
6       CTB     100              17
7       CTB     500.52           83
```

Now, the complex part I have to calculate another amount by multiplying this percentage to an amount from another table say table2 
ii) update the Total amount column by spilt the total amount column of table 1 into 2 rows – 1st row of the new Calculate PledgeAmount and 2nd row –  (totalAmount – PledgeAmount)

*Select t1.percentage * t2.new amount as [PledgeAmount]
From table 1 join table2 where t1.item=t2.item*

. e.g. for col1 Amount of  5558767.82   will split into two rows.
Final Result sample for :-

```
Col1    item    TotalAmount   Type   
1       ABC     363700.00     Pledge
1       ABC     5195067.82    Unpledge
```

....

I am using Temporary table to do calculations.
One of the way I think is to calculate the Pledged and Unpledged amount as new column and Pivot it but its huge table with hundreds of columns it will not perform fast.

Any other efficient way?

Comment: "but its huge table with hundreds of columns" -- Columns? Really? - But what's keeping you from simply using a temporary table to store the total amount per item. From there it should be easy to proceed.

Comment: This 3 columns are just part of the huge table. I am already keeping the value for total amount per item in Temp table. Sorry I am not great in explaining :(  I calculated the percentage but the part to split the total amount  into rows by multiplying the new percetage with tabl2 and row2 as difference .

Answer (score 0):

You can use a windowing function to solve this problem -- first in a sub-query calculate the total and then in the main query the percent:

```
 Select *, (totalAmount/total_for_item)*100 as percent_of_total
 from (
   SELECT t.*,
          SUM(totalAmount) OVER (PARTITION BY item) as total_for_item
   FROM table t
 ) sub
```

Comment: Thanks, but how about the 2nd part of splitting or updating the original total amount into 2 rows ?

Comment: I see ... two questions in one.  Typically frowned on here...  In fact, your 2nd part makes no sense to me.  Please read the how to ask a question part of the FAQ and phrase this question with a list of inputs and expected outputs at the least.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's get the total amount per item:

```
SELECT item, SUM( totalAmount ) as sumTotal
INTO #totalperitem
FROM table1
GROUP BY item
```

Now it's easy to get to the percentages:

```
SELECT t1.Col1,
       t1.item,
       t1.totalAmount,
       t1.totalAmount/tpi.sumTotal*100 AS percentage
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN #totalperitem tpi on ...
```

Tricky part: Separate rows with/without match in `table2`. Can be done with a `WHERE NOT EXISTS`, or, my preference, with a single outer join:

```
SELECT t1.item,
       CASE WHEN tpledged.item IS NULL
         THEN "Unpledged"
         ELSE "Pledged"
       END,
       SUM( t1.totalAmount ) AS amount
FROM table1 t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 tpledged ON t1. ... = tpledged. ...
GROUP BY t1.item,
         CASE WHEN tpledged.item IS NULL
           THEN "Unpledged"
           ELSE "Pledged"
         END
```

The basic trick is to create an artificial column from the presence/absence of records in `table2` and to also group by that artificial column.